# Distribution of tokens in Standard 4 player catan?

Tags: catan

My 4 player catan set has been mixed with my 5 & 6 player expansion set, parts have been lost, and last time I played we had 3 fields with an '8', no number '2' and a missing '10'.

Would someone be so kind as to run through the values in the standard game - i.e. A-R where A=x, etc…

Comment: Related: [same question for the 5–6 player expansion](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/49229/38194)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here you go:

- A = 5
- B = 2
- C = 6
- D = 3
- E = 8
- F = 10
- G = 9
- H = 12
- I = 11
- J = 4
- K = 8
- L = 10
- M = 9
- N = 4
- O = 5
- P = 6
- Q = 3
- R = 11

Comment: Thanks! Is that all of them? I'd better get busy with paper and scissors…

Comment: @Edd - Yup, for 4 players, that is all of them.  You should be done in no time :)

Comment: Is there any meaning of the letters besides to identify them? When people ask what they mean I always have to confess that I have no idea.

Comment: The letters are just to put them in proper order. You start at an Edge with A, and continue alphabetically until you hit R. You skip the desert. The dots under the number indicate the relative frequency the number is rolled to give some at-a-glance clue to which spots are best. 6 and 8 are the most often rolled (aside from 7) so those are red.

Comment: I've marked the back of my 5-6 player ones, so I can tell them apart.

Comment: Interesting -- the backs on my 5-6 player expansion are speckled (in addition to the letter), while the original ones are plain.  The same is true for the tiles.

Answer (score 4):

Another method:

I've noticed that my 5-6 player tokens have very dark gray numbers vs the normal tokens that have black numbers. It's hard to tell, but I could separate the two if I had to.

The answer given by @LittleBobbyTables is correct, but I probably won't have easy access this webpage (unless I print it) when the blunder that mixes my number tokens occurs. If you know this trick, you'll have a fallback method. Note that this may or may not work depending on what edition your game is (mine is 4th).

Comment: Agreed, although my expansion has brown numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a computer and an internet handy, [this](http://bettersettlers.com/) could solve all your troubles.

Comment: Have you any experience with that?  It looks interesting, but I was unable to find exactly what they're doing to ensure a better experience .. so I'm a bit skeptical.

Comment: I think I heard some rumor at work that the guy who runs that site works or used to work at my company, so I'll see.

Comment: I wrote Better Settlers. The main goal of it is to try to lay out the tiles/probabilities/harbors in such a way that it's random, but in a fair way. My friends and I got tired of playing games where the winner was decided with the initial placements. Since it doesn't follow the traditional "spiral out with numbers" strategy, it also adds more variability to games. Some people love it, some hate it, but if you have further questions (stackexchange comments don't allow full explanations :), feel free to ping me emailus(at)bettersettlers.com. There's also an Android app for those interested