# When and Why did the Catan number distribution change

Tags: catan

I've recently had to replace my 3rd Edition Catan set and the new version has a different number distribution as shown in these two images taken from the respective rule books.

[image: Catan 3rd Edition Numbers]

[image: Catan 5th Edition Numbers]

Is there a reason that the layout has changed? Using the 5th edition set up, we've had both nines touching, and looking at the layout below it seems possible to have a 6 and 8 together which is disallowed by the rules under variable set-up in the Almanac. These oddities never happened with the spiral A-B-C set up in the 3rd edition.

Comment: The first image does not appear to be from the third edition rulebook; likely it's fourth edition.

Comment: I was under the impression those number plates are supposed to be placed at random

Comment: @npst they've got letters on the back so you can place them in sequence. Though the 5th edition rules do have a snippet for randomly placing them, ensuring no red numbers are adjacent. Inspiration! This might be why they're different. If the letters are only for the intro game, with the setup in the image with defined starting points for better balance, they then don't have to be the same as a set up that tries for balance when using the placement rules for the advanced game, which the older sets went for.

Comment: @npst, There are two official ways of doing it: According to the preset layout (which this question is about), or random with the caveat that no two reds touch each other.

Comment: I think the distribution of the numbers is the same, (one of 2 and 12 each, two of all others). I suppose you mean the layout when the numbers are ordered by the letters, but I don't see letters in the lower picture, so I'm not exactly sure. (Also, if those are the ordered spiral setups, I can't see how you'd get the nines together either.)

Comment: @ilkkachu good point about the 9s. I will have to lay out the tokens and double check, but it did happen on the first set up.

Comment: @ikkachu it turns out the layout using the A-B-C on the back of the number tokens in the box does not match the one in the provided image. The image in the variable set up section matches the older version. So I'm beginning to think the letters on the back of the tokens are simply wrong. Misprinted in the particular run that I have possibly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having spent a bit more time with the rule book and the internet I've come to the conclusion this is a combination of two factors.

1. The image supplied above from the 5th edition rule book is a beginner set up that has no relation to the letters on the back of the number chits. It is purely a "balanced", and non-blocking starting point allowing new players to get into the game without too much trouble.
2. There's a printing error on the Chits in my copy (no idea how wide spread it is).

The printing error has two separate sources of verification.
This [Distribution Question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/distribution-of-tokens-in-standard-4-player-catan) include a list of the Letter to number combinations that match my older set and (really tellingly) match this image from the Almanac of the fifth edition.

[image: Variable Set up, illustration Q]

The numbers I have are in a slightly different sequence such that one 6 is swapped with an 11 (I and P), and one 9 is swapped with a 5 (M and O). Which leads to commonly paired 9s and 11s. Given the image Q above, this is probably a printing error.

Answer (score 4):

The [5th edition](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_5th_ed_rules_eng_150303.pdf) of Catan changed a number of cosmetic things from the [4th edition](https://www.catan.com/en/download/?SoC_rv_Rules_091907.pdf); including a full re-editing of the rules for clarity, but there wasn't much in the way of actual rule changes.
The biggest change with the updated rules is the reworked setup for the *non-randomized* beginner game.

The 'Variable' and 'Fully Random' set-up are essentially unchanged, with the biggest difference being the letters are now on the back of the number tokens.

It is worth noting that while there aren't any actual changes to the rules between the 4th and 5th editions, as you're moving from the 3rd to the 5th you'll notice two differences:

1. You can now move the Robber to the desert
2. The 'Soldier' card is now a 'Knight' card

Comment: “You can now move the Robber to the desert” Wow, we’ve always played that way and never realized it wasn’t in the rules.

Comment: The no rules change part of this answer leads me to believe the problem I'm having is a printing error on the tokens in my set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are confusing the premade example setups with the randomized setup.

The 2 pictures you show are premade setups, and both can be used to do a premade setup where the resources will flow well and are good for beginners. But these setups are supposed to be used "as is" with the exact tile and number setup.

The premade number setup is not supposed to be used with random resource tiles as you are suggesting so a 6 or an 8 will never touch, not in the premade setups nor in the 5th edition random setups.

Once you have "graduated" from the pre-made setups, you can advance to the randomized setups. In the randomized setups you can either shuffle the numbers either completely random or place them according to the alfabetic numbering on the back.

If you use the complete random setup you must indeed lookout for 8's touching 6's, which is never allowed no matter the edition version. So if this happens you have to "manually" adjust the numbers. With the alfabetic numbering you can't put 8's and 6's next to eachother when placed correctly.

Why there is a difference between the 2 example setups I don't know, but I would take it as a good thing, and try both example setups before playing randomized setups, both example setups are compliant with the placement rules of the latest 5th edition.

Edit: Furthermore I have confirmed that the 4th edition and the 5th edition have the same alfabetic order on the back of the numbers which is the following:
A=5 - B=2 - C=6 - D=3 - E=8 - F=10 - G=9 - H=12 - I=11 - J=4 - K=8 - L=10 - M=9 - N=4 - O=5 - P=6 - Q=3 - R=11

Comment: Yes, I think that's part of it. The odd thing is the letters on the back of the numbers make no sense for either scenario as they don't match the beginner image and for an intermediate random set up lead to very bad clumping of numbers. The letters on the back of older editions didn't give this issue no matter where the desert fell within the sequence.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with the 5th edition alfabetic random setup ... not sure what you mean. I will take a look at it.

Comment: Okay, I just checked the 5th edition and the 4th edition numbers, and they are exactly the same. Both the 4th regular edition and the 4th 10year anniversary edition. I will list them here : A=5 - B=2 - C=6 - D=3 - E=8 - F=10 - G=9 - H=12 - I=11 - J=4 - K=8 - L=10 - M=9 - N=4 - O=5 - P=6 - Q=3 - R=11

Comment: Also, what do you mean by intermediate random setup? You use the same tile placement of a premade setup and then use random number placing? Which obviously should work fine. Furthermore, I have never had any issues with the 4th or 5th edition numbers using them alfabetically, and we have played 100+ games with both random tiles and "semi random" alfabetic numbers.

Comment: Alright I see you say third edition, I don't think I ever owned a third edition, then again, I have not encountered the weird numbers you talk about. The numbers are always spread out nicely (logically because the numbers basically are placed the same every time, only the tiles change).

Comment: The "intermediate random" set up would be shuffle and place hexes anywhere, and put the numbers out alphabetically. The set you have is different from the numbers I have which is why I think it's a printing error as mentioned in my answer. My I and P are swapped compared to yours I=6 and P=11, similarly teh M and O are swapped. M=5 and P=9. This leads to a lot of 9s sitting next to each other, and 11 doing the same. Obviously the numbers do move around a little, depending on where the desert is, but with my set I always had joined 11s unless desert was in centre and usually joined 9s.

Comment: Alright, then indeed your letters are wrong, and a misprint. Since now you have my correct numbers you can re-label them accordingly so you have a correct setup :p And now I also understand your intermediate setup, an advanced setup would then be completely random numbers, I will add this to my houserules :)