# Are the expansion number tokens in 5-6 players expansion different from the basic Catan?

Tags: catan

I am currently in the process of creating my own custom Catan board and wish to create number tokens for both original and 5-6 players extension gameplay. I have managed to find a detailed list of the original number tokens already, but cannot locate the list of the extension tokens (I only know there are 28 of them).

Could anyone let me know what numbers come under thoe 28, how many of them and whether of not they have alphabetical letters as well?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Someone has created a pdf with all this information over on [BGG here](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/13271/settlerssetupspdf)

If you dont have a BGG account to view the file I've converted it to a jpg for you.

[image: Image of card and token distribution for Catan]

Comment: Is there a meaning to the boxes around the I's and N's?

Comment: @Jonita,  sorry I don't know.  The question was just about number for each letter token and that a reference I found.  Maybe post a question to BGG user who made the original file on there?

Comment: @Jontia, the letter/number combinations with the box are unchanged, the others are changed.